# Concat 2 JSX elements

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have this in **`render()`**.

```
render() {
    let caret = <span className="caret"></span>;
    let submenuHtml = this.props.submenu.map((menuItem, index)=> <span>{menuItem.name}</span>);

    return(submenuHtml);
  }
```

I need to return `caret + submenuHtml` without any wrapping div or span so that the returned html will look like:

```
<span className="caret"></span>
<span>Menu1</span>
<span>Mennu2</span>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `React.Fragment`:

```
return (
  <React.Fragment> 
    {caret}
    {submenutHtml}
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

or

```
return (
  <> 
    {caret}
    {submenutHtml}
  </>
);
```

See [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Comment: Is that different from `return([caret,submenuHtml]);` ?

Comment: @phpsessionid Yes, it is not returning an array.

Comment: @phantomCoder However, with arrays you should be adding `key` to every element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can, do it as follows:

```
render() { 
    let caret = <span className="caret"></span>
    let submenuHtml = this.props.submenu.map((menuItem, index)=> {
    return <span>{menuItem.name}</span>
    });

return(
       {caret}
       {submenuHtml}
    ); 
}
```

This should works.